# Getting enemies / mushroom houses to reappear on the world map

Tags: new-super-mario-bros-u

On World 1 - Acorn Plains, there's a Piranha Plant that appears on the world map. He goes in and out of his pipe. If you beat him he disappears.

In the course of me playing the game I've observed that he eventually re-appears. But what are the specific conditions that need to be met for enemies on the world map to reappear? Do they reappear after *x* minutes? I beat a level just now and the Piranha Plant did not reappear. Maybe I need to beat multiple levels?

On that same note, do mushroom houses reappear after you've used them? FWIW I've beat The Final Battle in World 8 - Peach's Castle, and have three gold stars on the menu screen.

Comment: IIRC it happens whenever you get a game over or exit your save entirely and re-load, but I could be wrong its been years.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes things like enemies and toad houses can reappear if you do either of three things:

- Die (game over)
- Play through a certain amount of levels, or
- Beat the game by defeating Bowser